# Iframe and Firefox/IE bug

Tags: iframe

I try `<iframe>` for the content and use `position: fixed;` for a music player player bar to keep it at the bottom of the page.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/vhLeE/

HTML:

```html
<iframe src="http://thinkingstiff.com"></iframe>
<div id="player">music player</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%; 
}

iframe {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#player {
    background-color: black;
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 30px;   
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Sadly this doesn't work well for IE or Firefix 9, it simply shows the content in a small height window: http://cl.ly/0y0T2I1R042c3G002H3y

how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've seen a similar problem before with things I've worked on, and fortunately the workaround is really simple -- IE and Firefox just need the html height to be set to 100% as well.  So update the first element of your style to be:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%; 
}
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider dividing `iframe` and `div` heights in percentages. If you specify `100%` for `iframe`, div might hide the scrollbars.

you may change it to

```
iframe {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 97%;
    width: 100%;
}
#player {
    background-color: black;
    bottom: 0;
    color: white;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 3%;   
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vhLeE/3/